# bnx2 kernel module not functioning correctly

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I have an HP ProLiant server that is running Debian 5. After a reboot, it is not able to bring up any of it's interfaces. If I run `ifup eth0`, it gives me an error about the device not existing. (It has 4 Broadcom NetXtreme II interfaces.) I verified that it has a bnx2 driver (`lsmod | grep bnx2`). Then I tried unloading and reloading the driver (`rmmod bnx2 && modprobe bnx2`) and all of a sudden my interfaces work! Now I can `ifup eth0` without any issues.

After restarting, though, the same problem arises.

My question is, can anybody speculate about what would cause a .ko to not work after a reboot, but then to work correctly after unloading and reloading it?

I'm guessing it's some kind of timing issue with the NIC hardware, or its a dependency issue with another .ko. Any ideas how to resolve it so that it will come up correctly after a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Debian systems you can just add the module name to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and then run `update-initramfs -k all -u`

Comment: Thanks, Rudy. Both good answers but my distro (which I failed to specify) was Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to to be related to an incompatibility of the NIC. What Linux distribution are you using?

I came across the same issue on SUSE Linux. I got it to work by adding the `bnx2` module `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` and regenerating a new initrd

If your distro is SuSE, add `bnx2` in to the `INITRD_MODULE` list and then recreate a new initrd using `mkinitrd`

```
INITRD_MODULES="cciss jbd ext3 scsi_mod bnx2"
```